# altering the color of one value in a ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a simplified dataframe

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(wins=c(1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,3))
ggplot(df,aes(x=wins))+geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5,fill="red")
```

I would like to get the final value in the sequence,3, shown with either a different fill or alpha. One way to identify its value is

```
tail(df,1)$wins
```

In addition, I would like to have the histogram bars  shifted so that they are centered over the number. I tried unsuccesfully subtracting from the wins value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To draw bins in different colors you can use `geom_histogram()` for subsets.

2) To center bars along numbers on the x axis you can invoke `scale_x_continuous(breaks=..., labels=...)`

So, this code

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(wins=c(1,1,3,1,1,2,11,2,11,15,1,1,3))
cond <- df$wins == tail(df,1)$wins

ggplot(df, aes(x=wins)) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(df,cond==FALSE), binwidth=0.5, fill="red") +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(df,cond==TRUE), binwidth=0.5, fill="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$wins+0.25, labels=df$wins)
```

produces the plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I cater for instances where, say, one of the values was 15. I would want it to be to the far right of graph - at the appropriate separation from the others but it actually would appear between the 1 and 2 values as it is no longer numeric?

Comment: You can just remove `as.factor()`. In this case bins wouldn't be centered against numbers on x axis.

Comment: Tx. I have accepted your answer but posted an edit which satisfies all of my needs. Hopefully it will be accepted for viewing

Comment: @pssguy I think the usual SO practice is to provide such update in your question itself. I reviewed but didn't approve your edit, someone else might but if I were you I would add that to my question

Comment: @Miserable Variable. Thanks never had to do this before

Comment: I updated my solution, now it solves both problems with color and centering.

Comment: It could be done with a single `geom_histogram` if you made `cond` a column `df$cond <- df$wins == tail(df,1)$wins` and used it inside `aes`, `ggplot(df, aes(x=wins, fill = cond))`.  That's the usual way to control colours in ggplot2.

Comment: @nacnudus but how do you set the color of that specific bar you want to change??

Comment: @Seymour see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single `geom_histogram()` by using `aes(fill = cond)`.

To choose different colours, use one of the `scale_fill_*()` functions, e.g. `scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")`.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(wins=c(1,1,3,1,1,2,11,2,11,15,1,1,3))
df$cond <- df$wins == tail(df,1)$wins
ggplot(df, aes(x=wins, fill = cond)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$wins+0.25, labels=df$wins) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]