# ggplot2: how to color specific bins in histogram based on bin ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am plotting a histogram with ggplot2 and trying to figure out how to color specific bins in another color than the others. The bins I want to color are defined by their bin edges / ranges.

Similar questions I found were asking for conditional coloring based on the original values, not the bin ranges, [either for a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372523/altering-the-color-of-one-value-in-a-ggplot-histogram) or [using a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721820/how-to-color-a-ggplot-histogram-differently-based-on-precise-cut-off-points).

Example:

```
dt <- data.table(x = runif(10000))

ggplot(dt, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0, closed = "left", 
                 col = "darkgreen", fill = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

which gives me this plot:

[image: plot]

I defined the leftmost bin to be [0, 0.01), from there the others are calculated.

Now I want to color the following bins differently: [0, 0.01), [0.1, 0.11), [0.2, 0.21) ..., i.e. the bins starting at

```
> seq(0, 1, 0.1)
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

How can I do this?

---

EDIT: this is my desired plot:

[image: plot_goal]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

davidnortes' answer shows colors well, here's an option if you only want to highlight *some* bins. I'll start with `cut` to pre-identify some bins (this needs to be kept in-sync with your `binwidth=` and other options to `geom_histogram`), and then a simple logical to determine which ones to highlight.

```r
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  mutate(
    grp = cut(x, seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE),
    is6 = between(grp, 60, 69)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = is6)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0, closed = "left", 
                   col = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

[image: single highlight]

Options:

- to remove the `is6` legend, add `+ scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")`
- if you want multiple distinct bands, perhaps `case_when` can help, noting that `is6` does not need to be logical:

  ```r
  dt %>%
    mutate(
      grp = cut(x, seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE), 
      highlight = case_when(
        between(grp, 60, 69) ~ "A",
        between(grp, 20, 25) ~ "B",
        TRUE ~ "C")
    ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, fill = highlight)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0, closed = "left", 
                     col = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
  ```

  The `scale_fill_discrete` works for this, too.
- you may want specific colors for each group of `highlight` or such, use `scale_fill_manual`.

[image: multiple bin colors]

---

**Edit**:

Here's your image, colors notwithstanding:

```r
dt %>%
  mutate(
    grp = (x %% 0.1 < 0.01)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = grp)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0, closed = "left", 
                   col = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

[image: updated ggplot2]

Comment: works nicely, thanks! I managed to produce the same plot that I added as my desired output plot. Looking at the interval identifiers produced by `cut`, the easiest way to identify the intervals I want to color is actually `highlight = grp %in% c(1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91)`

Comment: no need for `grp %in%`, you can use my modulus trick (just edited). Glad it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create ranges of values along your variable X and color them differently, you can use the `cut` function:

> cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.

So, tweaking a little your code, you would have:

```
#Grouping variable 'x' in dt according sequence 'seq(0, 1, 0.1)'    
dt$breaks <- cut(dt$x, breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))

#Plotting
ggplot(dt, aes(x, col = breaks, fill = breaks)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0, closed = "left", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: *"how to color specific bins in another color than the others"*, to me this sounds like one or more bins are colored distinctly from all others, not necessarily that all bins have unique colors.

Comment: It might be as well, but I went with intervals because of his statement: "The bins I want to color are defined by their bin edges / ranges." so if he/she is trying to discriminate by ranges I would go with `cut`

Comment: @r2evans is right. I don't want to color the whole range [0, 0.1), but rather [0, 0.01), then [0.1, 0.11), etc. I updated my question to show a desired plot.